Load cycler keeps stalling at same voltage
Hello I am building a load cycler using an arduino with this code:
bool in_charge_mode;
int cycles = 0;
float cutoffvoltage = 2.0f;
float get_batt_voltage() { return analogRead(A1) * 5.0f / 1023.0f; }
void set_charge_mode() {
in_charge_mode = true; // remember state
digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //start charge
digitalWrite(12, LOW); //stop discharging to load
}
void set_discharge_mode() {
in_charge_mode = false;
digitalWrite(13, LOW); //stop charge
digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //discharge to load
}
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //Connected to relay 1 which is relay for load
pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //Connected to relay 2 which is relay for charger
// Check initial voltage
float vbat = get_batt_voltage();
if(vbat < cutoffvoltage) {
// battery is below the cutoff voltage, we need to start charging
set_charge_mode();
} else {
// we can discharge if above cutoff voltage
set_discharge_mode();
}
}
void loop() {
if(cycles >= 500) {
Serial.println("Refusing to do anything, number of cycles too high");
set_charge_mode(); // to disconnect from load or something
return;
}
float vbat = get_batt_voltage();
Serial.println("Battery voltage: " + String(vbat) + " is charging: " + String(in_charge_mode));
if(in_charge_mode) {
if(vbat > 4.2f) {
// we're done charging! increase cycle counter
cycles++; // technically, this is the number of "charge ups complete"
Serial.println("BATTERY CHARGED SUFFICIENTLY. Discharging again.");
set_discharge_mode();
} else {
Serial.println("Still charging up the battery, waiting..");
}
} else {
// in discharge mode
if(vbat < cutoffvoltage) {
// battery has sunk below our cutoff voltage, we need to charge up again
Serial.println("BATTERY DISCHARGED. Charging up again.");
set_charge_mode();
} else {
Serial.println("Still dicharging the battery, waiting..");
}
}
delay(1000); // check again in one second
}

and after waiting ~2 hours the serial monitor just keeps outputting over and over:
Battery voltage: 4.18 is charging: 0
Still dicharging the battery, waiting..
Battery voltage: 4.18 is charging: 0
Still dicharging the battery, waiting..
Battery voltage: 4.18 is charging: 0

I double checked with my multimeter and it is also showing that the voltage hasn't changed at all after 2 hours of supposedly discharging.
I also checked the relay board and only one led is on which implies that only one relay is on during the discharging.
I am unsure what could be the issue whether it is hardware or software.
This is the circuit:


What is that "Charger", exactly?

Hi it is a TP4056 1A Li-Ion Battery Charger Board Micro USB

Is it powered from the same supply as the Arduino? That could provide a negative connection that bypasses the relay.

No it is powered using a 5V microusb charger which is separate from anything

And what is the load? How much current does it take? Is it definitely connected and working?

the load is a 1 meter piece of nichrome wire that has been coiled multiple times. What should I do to check if it is working? I checked the continuity and everything seems connected.

Does the wire get hot? If you measure the battery voltage with a meter does it match what your code is saying?

Hi I think there might be something wrong with the measuring. When I take out the battery completely the serial monitor doesn't change and it keeps outputting the same stuff. Also when I take out the battery, the battery charger indicator goes from red(charging) to blue (not charging). So I'm guessing this is part of the problem?

I don't see any code to set up your analog input pin for read operations.

Isn't it this line -> float get_batt_voltage() { return analogRead(A1) * 5.0f / 1023.0f; }

No, that reads the pin. You set up pins 12 and 13 for output but not A1 for input.

Sorry do you think you could explain further? You say to get the input for A1, isn't that the same thing as reading the pin?

No. Setting up a pin for output isn't the same as writing to it, and setting up a pin for input is not the same as reading from it. The first operation enables the second to work.

How would I then write it in the code so that it can read the operations?

@Finbarr On many Arduino boards you can use analogRead() without configuring the input. This is implicit done by the runtime lib.

It may be possible, that you don't use the correct relay contacts, but the green drawing hides the board printing. I think you must use the left and the right screw of each relay triple. The contacts read from left to right looks like COM - NC - NO, and you need the switch between COM and NO. The software looks OK at the first glance but needs better indentation.

hi I figured out one of the problems was that I switched the wiring for the load and charger so now that's fixed. Now the system is able to charge and discharge properly! But now im having trouble with the serial monitor outputting inaccurate readings for the voltage -> sometimes it reads 3.6V when the voltage is 4.0V for examples. The readings are all over the place. What could be causing these inaccurate readings?
